How do I get reference to imported model and Babylon methods
I imported a model using the example
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import '@babylonjs/loaders';
import { Vector3 } from 'babylonjs';
import { Engine, Scene, ArcRotateCamera, HemisphericLight, Model } from 'react-babylonjs';

const App = () => (

<ArcRotateCamera
name="camera"
target={new Vector3(0, 1, 0)}
alpha={-Math.PI / 2}
beta={Math.PI / 4}
radius={5}
/>

<HemisphericLight
name="light1"
intensity={0.7}
direction={new Vector3(0, 1, 0)}
/>

<Model
rootUrl="/"
sceneFilename="Duck.glb"
position={new Vector3(0, 0, 0)}
scale={new Vector3(1, 1, 1)}
/>
);

export default App;

I want to get a reference to the imported model (or AbstractMesh) to derive its boundingInfo [using mesh.getBoundingInfo()]. Also any example to use other methods such to setAbsolutePosition, addRotation on the mesh ?
This will allow me to transform the imported model (reposition, rotate) using Babylon API. I can do this with the imperative approach, but how to access these methods using the declarative approach
